# Differences in Person Account and Contact Access, how is this possible?

Tags: person-accounts, access, insufficient-privileges

We have person account enabled in our org.

So our contacts are set to `Controlled by parent`.

I was debugging `Insufficient accesss rights on object id`, and found out that for Task we have whoId which is PersonContactId and for that[image] user has only read access.

Where as the Account which is the parent of this contact for that user has edit, read and transfer access.

[image]

This should be impossible as we don't control contact access from anywhere.
On task Name goes as `whoid` and whoid is always person contact id, hence the user is not able to change assigned to field, even if he has Account edit access.

Comment: I tried to replicate this scenario by giving `Public read/write` to account in sharing settings and `controlled by parent` in contact. I can see that UserRecordAccess has the same values for both PersonContactId and Personaccount. Can you tell how did you give the edit, read and transfer access for the account? Thanks

Comment: If Account is `Public read/write` teh Contact is also `Public read/write` that is why `UserRecordAccess` has same values , try giving Account as `Private`.

Comment: Also from profile level, give Account as read, write and Contact  as Read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task has look up as `Name` and `Related To`.

On Task we only add Contact in `Name`, which gets automatically created in our system as we enabled person account.

So if a User does not have edit access to Contact, he will not get edit access to `Task` too even if he has Account edit access from Profile level, though clicking `Name` on Task will navigate to Account.

We gave contact edit access from profile level too and this got resolved.